# How to match an output value with JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sort of new to javascript and trying to figure out a way how i can match an output value with JSON key data and show it as a Tooltip label.

Below is the JSON data format:

```
{
  "status": [
    {
      "Pass": "You have passed this exam"
    },
    {
      "Fail": "You have failed this exam"
    },
  ]
}
```

Below is the function where I am trying to show logic:

```
export default function UnConfirmed() {

return {
    label   : "Unconfirmed",
    content : (
      <>
        {data && (
          <>
            {!data?.attemptedModules?.attemptedModule?.length ? (
              <Text>There is currently no record of you ever having enrolled on any modules.</Text>
            ) : !filteredData?.length ? (
              <Text>You currently do not have any unconfirmed marks.</Text>
            ) : (
            sortData?.map((module) => (
          <Box key={module.code} className="marks">
            <H3 title={module.fullName} />
            <UweDescriptionList
              keyValue={module.code}
              className="module-details"
              items={[
                { name: 'Credit status', description: <Tooltip label={"This will further explain your credit status"} text={module.creditStatus} /> },
                { name: 'Decision', description: <Tooltip label={"This will further explain the decision."} text={module.decision} /> },
              ]}
            />
          </Box>
              ))
            )}
          </>
        )}
      </>
    ),
  };
}
```

For example: if the returning value of {module.decision} is 'Pass',it will match the JSON keyword 'Pass' and will show the corresponding value ("You have passed this exam") in the tooltip label.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a small nesting, the code will be like this

```
const output = JsonConstantName.status.find((el) => Object.keys(el).includes(module.decision))[module.decision];
```